# Showing $P^2=P$ for $P(v)=\frac{\langle v,w\rangle }{||w||^2}w$

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

My book asserts that for fixed $w$ where $w\neq 0$ that $P^2=P$ for $P(v)=\frac{\langle v,w\rangle }{||w||^2}w$

My book has a general corralary that $v\to P(v)$ is a bounded linear transformation and the fact that $P^2=P$ implies it is a projection. I'm not sure how they made the assertation. Any ideas?

Comment: That $\;P\;$ is in fact the *orthogonal* projection on $\;\langle w\rangle\;$ ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$\require{cancel}P^2(v)=P(P(v))=P\left(\frac{\langle v,w\rangle }{||w||^2}w\right)=\frac{\langle v,w\rangle }{||w||^2}P\left(w\right)=\frac{\langle v,w\rangle }{||w||^2}\cancelto{=1}{\frac{\langle w,w\rangle }{||w||^2}}w=P(v)$$

Moreover, we have by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$||P(v)||=\left|\frac{\langle v,w\rangle }{||w||^2}\right|\cdot||w||\le \frac{||v||||w||}{||w||^2}\cdot||w||=||v||$$
hence $P$ is bounded and 
$$||P||\le1$$
and if $v\in \operatorname{Im}(P)$ then $P(v)=v$ and then $||P(v)||=||v||$ so
$$||P||\ge 1$$
and we conclude that
$$||P||=1$$

Comment: Thank you, why does the P function only get applied to the w?

Comment: The projection $P$ is linear so we have
$$P(\lambda w)=\lambda P(w)$$

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: In the first line just before the very last equality a vector $\;w\;$ is lacking...

Comment: Thank you @DonAntonio you're always vigilant!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$P^2(v)=P(P(v))=\frac{\langle P(v),w\rangle}{\|w\|^2}w$$

Comment: Sami worked from the outside in, while I'm working from the inside out.